# How can I efficiently calculate region centroids with non-uniform densities?

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, computational-geometry

Say I have a rectangle of length 100 and width 1. I can very quickly find its centroid with `RegionCentroid`. But suppose that the farther to the right you are on the rectangle, the denser it is. To find the centroid in this case (imagine finding a point such that you could balance the rectangle on the tip of a pencil at that point), you have to account for the densities. Now I can no longer use builtin `RegionCentroid`, but the math is quite simple:

```
Timing[
  length = 100;
  squaretable = Table[Rectangle[{i - 1, 0}], {i, 1, length}];
  bigrectangle = RegionUnion[squaretable];
  squareMF = RegionMember[#] & /@ squaretable;
  dens = Range[length]; 
  densAtPoint[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
    First[dens[[FirstPosition[squareMF[[#]][{x, y}] & /@ Range[length], True]]]];
  centroid = 
    NIntegrate[{x, y}*densAtPoint[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bigrectangle] /
    NIntegrate[densAtPoint[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bigrectangle]]

 (*{2.65625, {66.5, 0.5}}*)
```

The problem is that this appears to be highly inefficient. If I increase the length by a factor of ten, the computation time increases by a factor of roughly 100. How can I calculate this centroid more efficiently when I have larger regions (with more subregions with their own densities)?

I'm not looking for an answer that exploits the particular predictability of the density in the MWE that I've given -- please don't tell me to rewrite `densAtPoint[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Ceiling[x];`!

Comment: @MarcoB I think you're correct. Thanks to both you and Carl Woll. Before I accept it as a duplicate, let me try the implementation proposed to make sure that there aren't challenges unique to my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is helpful, but one idea is to add a dimension representing the density to your regions. Then you can use [`RegionCentroid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid) of this $n+1$ dimensional object and take the first $n$ coordinates: Here is an example:

```
cond = Or @@ Table[i-1<x<i && 0<y<1 && 0<z<i, {i, 100}];
Most @ RegionCentroid @ ImplicitRegion[cond, {x,y,z}]
```

> {133/2, 1/2}